# "Using $this when not in object context" appears in Silex/phpunit case

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, this, silex

I have a Silex application that works fine local and as well on the server. Just my phpunit tests throw an exception while I start them (ONLY ON THE SERVER, local they're work as well):

"Using $this when not in object context"

I changed my code and don't cache the firewall anymore and it works fine (have a look at the commented part):

```
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;

class SecurityProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {

    //private $firewall;

    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['firewall'] = $app->protect(function () use ($app) {
            // FIXME phpunit tests on server don't like the $this reference (no idea why?)
            /*if($this->firewall == null) {
                $this->firewall = new Firewall($app);
            }
            return $this->firewall;*/
            return new Firewall($app);
        });
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
    }
}
```

Any one an idea why I got the exception?

Thanks guys!

Comment: function () use ($app, $this) { ... } ???

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Depending on the version you might need different adjustments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `$this` inside a closure. Prior to 5.4, the `$this` could not be used inside the closure. Since 5.4, `$this` refers to the object that it is declared in.

To be able to run your tests in PHP 5.3, you have to use something like:

```
public function register(Application $app)
{
    $that = $this;

    $app['firewall'] = $app->protect(function () use ($app, $that) {
        if($that->firewall == null) {
            $that->firewall = new Firewall($app);
        }

        return $that->firewall;
    });
}
```

Comment: Whoop-whoop! That's it! Thank you very much!